# I've nodeClone() a div. I want the element to show only one day in each clone not the whole array

Tags: arrays, clonenode

```
<div class="div-to-clone container text-center">
    <h3 class="text-center mb-3 day-of-week"></h3>
</div>       
<div class="target-1">
</div>

let divToClone = document.querySelector('.div-to-clone');
let target1 = document.querySelector(".target-1");
let h3 = document.querySelector('.day-of-week')

let days = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

console.log(days)


for(let i=0; i<7; i++){
    clone = divToClone.cloneNode(true);
    target1.appendChild(clone)
    console.log(target1)
};

//I'm trying to iterate through the array and append it to h3
```

So far I've been only able to have the whole array(all days in array) render in the h3 element. How do I iterate through it and have only display one day a time as it clones. `<h3>monday</h3><h3>tuesday</h3>` etc..  I've tried a nested for loop , mapping, append(). I don't understand how to iterate through it and append it to the element

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const newday = days.forEach(day => {
 // console.log(day)
 target1.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `<h3>${day}</h3>`)
 console.log(target1)
})
```